# Rails: Writing Search feature for database columns

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, search

I have to write a search functionality for my Rails application. I have multiples columns in database and user may wish to search based on any combination of columns from database. The way I have implement now is getting ugly. So I am guessing there may be gem for this or there may be better way to solve this problem. Below is snippet of my code.

```
class Finance < ActiveRecord::Base

  CASH_FLOW = ['Income', 'Expense']
  PAID_BY   = ['Person A', 'Person B']

  validates :amount,    presence: true
  validates :cash_flow, presence: true, inclusion: { in: CASH_FLOW }
  validates :date,      presence: true
  validates :paid_by,   inclusion: { in: PAID_BY }, if: "cash_flow == 'Expense'"
  validates :paid_by,   presence: true, if: "cash_flow == 'Expense'"

  def self.search(id, amount, amount_dropdown, cash_flow, start_date, finish_date, description, paid_by)
    if id.present? && amount.empty? && cash_flow.empty? && start_date.empty? && finish_date.empty? && description.empty? && paid_by.empty?
      Finance.find_by_id(id)
    elsif id.empty? && amount.present? && cash_flow.empty? && start_date.empty? && finish_date.empty? && description.empty? && paid_by.empty?
      Finance.where("amount #{amount_dropdown} ?", amount)
   elsif id.empty? && amount.empty? && cash_flow.present? && start_date.empty? && finish_date.empty? && description.empty? && paid_by.empty?
      Finance.where('cash_flow = ?', cash_flow)
   elsif id.empty? && amount.empty? && cash_flow.empty? && start_date.present? && finish_date.empty? && description.empty? && paid_by.empty?
      Finance.where('date = ?', Date.parse(start_date))
   elsif id.empty? && amount.empty? && cash_flow.empty? && start_date.empty? && finish_date.present? && description.empty? && paid_by.empty?
      Finance.where('date = ?', Date.parse(finish_date))
   elsif id.empty? && amount.empty? && cash_flow.empty? && start_date.present? && finish_date.present? && description.empty? && paid_by.empty?
      Finance.where('date >=  ? and date <= ?', Date.parse(start_date), Date.parse(finish_date))
   elsif id.empty? && amount.empty? && cash_flow.empty? && start_date.empty? && finish_date.empty? && description.present? && paid_by.empty?
      Finance.where('description like ?', "%#{description}%")
   elsif id.empty? && amount.empty? && cash_flow.empty? && start_date.empty? && finish_date.empty? && description.empty? && paid_by.present?
      Finance.where('paid_by = ?', paid_by)
   end
 end

end
```

Currently I am checking which fields are empty and which fields are present and based on that I am writing my search query. Please let me know how to do it better. I have to implement search feature for almost all the models.

Comment: It seems like you have to ensure that exactly one argument is passed to that method. If more than one parameter is present it wouldn't return anything. Does that make sense? If you have to ensure that when calling the method, why not use a specific finder in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is a good idea, especially if you have many models to search. There are some pretty solid solutions that would, out of the box, work better than your solution.

For example, you could use searchkick. It is very easy to implement and has a lot of features. In your case, it would be something like this:

```
def Finance
  searchkick

  self.search(....)
    Finance.reindex
    Finance.search ... 
  end
end
```

Check out their [github](https://github.com/ankane/searchkick) to see how you can customize the search.